# how to add custom 26rem value in max-height on tailwindcss

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm able to get up to 24rem on max-height using tailwindcss, but not 26rem. How would I  add this value? I was not able to find information on how to do this in the docs: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/max-height .  The only value-related changes I can find are for adding scale.  Thank you!

Comment: You can make use of config or you can use JWT if you can use it. with JWT you don't need to add config, just simply use `-max-h-[26rem]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add it manually on `tailwind.config.js` and recompile it

```
 theme: {
    extend: {
      height: {
        100: '24rem',
      },
    },
 },
```

therefore, you can use class `max-h-100` on your class list.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. You can add the values directly inside your class names like so: [follow the link](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-arbitrary-values)

`<div class="h-[250px] w-[30rem] absolute top-[1rem] ..."></div>`

2. the second approach is by using config file which locates in your project root directory: <<tailwind.config.js>>: [follow the link](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/height#customizing-your-theme)

```
module.exports = {
          theme: {
            extend: {
              height: {
                '128': '32rem',
              }
            }
          }
        }
```